# Python: reading text, readlines() vs iter()

Tags: python

I have a text file, with blocks of text, each separated by a line break. There are `M` blocks, each with `N` lines of text. I now want to read `n` lines for each of `m` blocks, where `n<=N` and `m<=M`.

I have tried something similar to the following:

```
num_blocks = 4 # or whatever value I choose
num_lines = 3 # or whatever value I choose

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    block_num = 0
    line_num = 0
    for line in lines:
        # do something with the line .....
        line_num += 1
        # has the specified number of lines been read?
        if line_num == num_lines:
            block_num += 1
            # has the specified number of blocks been read?
            if block_num == num_blocks:
                break;
            else:
                line_num = 0
```

However, when `n<N`, I need to skip over the remaining lines in the current block. I have tried putting

```
if line != '\n':
    continue
```

next to `# do something with the line .....`, but this then skips the entire first block.

Alternatively, I have tried creating an iterator `it = lines.iter()` and incrementing each one accordingly. The problem with this approach is that there is no way of knowing when the end of the file has been reached. `readlines()` does this for me, but I don't know how to know when the last line has been reached if I am using an interator.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `;` after `break`

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the end of an iterator like so:

```
try:
    it.next()
except StopIteration:
    *do something*
```

The StopIteration Exception is what an iterator throws when there is nothing left to iterate.